# List of data frames containing row and column indices to select data from a larger data frame

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames. One of the columns contains the name of the data frame:

```
a <- data.frame(PIN = c(1:3), Item = c("a", "a", "a"))
b <- data.frame(PIN = c(4:6), Item = c("b", "b", "b"))
List <- list(a, b)
```

And a larger data frame I want to extract data from.  The values in the first columns in my list of data frames correspond to the values in the first column or the larger data frame, and the names/values in the second columns of my list of data frames correspond to column names in the larger data frame:

```
DF <-data.frame(PIN = c(1:10), a = c(101:110), b = c(201:210), c = c(301:310))
```

I want to add columns to the data frames in my list extracting data from DF, using PIN as a row index and Item as a column index.  So essentially, I will end up with:

```
a <- data.frame(PIN = c(1:3), Item = c("a", "a", "a"), a = c(101:103))
b <- data.frame(PIN = c(4:6), Item = c("b", "b", "b"), b = c(204:206))
List <- list(a, b)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tidyr`, `dplyr` and `purrr` we could do:

```
DF <- tidyr::gather(DF, key = "Item", value, -PIN)

purrr::map(List, dplyr::left_join, DF, by = c("PIN", "Item"))
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>   PIN Item value
> 1   1    a   101
> 2   2    a   102
> 3   3    a   103
>
> [[2]]
>   PIN Item value
> 1   4    b   204
> 2   5    b   205
> 3   6    b   206
> ```

Note that you will get a warning message because the example data contains factors. Add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when constructing the data frames to avoid this warning message.

You can subsitute the `purrr` `map` function with base R's `lapply` using:

```
lapply(List, dplyr::left_join, DF, by = c("PIN", "Item"))
```

Additionally, one alternative to Uwe's solution could be:

```
library(tidyverse)

DF <- gather(DF, key = "Item", value, -PIN)

List %>% 
  map(mutate_if, is.factor, as.character) %>% # optional, but solves the warning message by converting factors to character
  map_df(rbind, .id = "id") %>% 
  left_join(DF) %>% 
  split(.$id)
```

> ```
> $`1`
>   id PIN Item value
> 1  1   1    a   101
> 2  1   2    a   102
> 3  1   3    a   103
>
> $`2`
>   id PIN Item value
> 4  2   4    b   204
> 5  2   5    b   205
> 6  2   6    b   206
> ```

---

Data:

```
# Create list
List <- list(
  data.frame(PIN = c(1:3), Item = c("a", "a", "a")),
  data.frame(PIN = c(4:6), Item = c("b", "b", "b"))
)

# Create data frame
DF <- data.frame(
  PIN = c(1:10), 
  a = c(101:110), 
  b = c(201:210), 
  c = c(301:310)
)
```

Comment: Np, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reconsider your data structures:

1. A list of equally structured data.frames can be combined into one larger data object which avoids to iterate over the list elements.
2. As the "payload" columns `a`, `b`, and `c` of `DF` all contain the same data type, `DF` can be reshaped from wide to long format. This converts the column names to data elements which can be more easily used for a lookup operation.

So, my suggestion is:

```
library(data.table)

keys <- rbindlist(List, idcol = TRUE)
DT <- setDT(melt(DF, id.vars = "PIN", variable.name = "Item"))
DT[keys, on = .(PIN, Item)]
```

> ```
>    PIN Item value .id
> 1:   1    a   101   1
> 2:   2    a   102   1
> 3:   3    a   103   1
> 4:   4    b   204   2
> 5:   5    b   205   2
> 6:   6    b   206   2
> ```

If you still need a list result:

```
split(DT[keys, on = .(PIN, Item)], by = ".id")
```

> ```
> $`1`
>    PIN Item value .id
> 1:   1    a   101   1
> 2:   2    a   102   1
> 3:   3    a   103   1
>
> $`2`
>    PIN Item value .id
> 1:   4    b   204   2
> 2:   5    b   205   2
> 3:   6    b   206   2
> ```